# Calling delegate method from IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

**I am unable to call**

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

**On following IBAction**

```
- (IBAction)button:(UIButton *)sender {


}
```

help me

Comment: That's not enough information.  Where is the reference to the map view stored in the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(IBAction)button:(UIButton *)sender {
        [self mapView:yourMapViewObject didUpdateUserLocation:yourLactionObject];
     }
```

Comment: Please add a bit more explanation so other users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You Can't explicitly call the delegate method of  **MKMapView**.

It will get called when the location of the user gets updated.

[Take a look at apple doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:)

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to call the same action for MKMapView delegate and button selector, create new function which is called from

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

and also which is called from your button selector. You shouldn't call MKMapView delegate method.